# Too many WebBrowsers causing crash in mshtml.dll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

The program I am writing takes a very large amount of html text, splits it up, and displays it in multiple WebBrowser controls. It is split up because the amount of text is so large that it cannot be placed in a single string variable, let alone a single WebBrowser control. This all seems to work well, up to a certain point. The point where it breaks seems to be after creating about 72 WebBrowser controls, with about 2000 lines of html in each one. Each browser is instantiated like so:

```
var browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("about:blank");
browser.Document.OpenNew(false);
browser.Document.Write(node.HTML);
```

After instantiating all of the webbrowsers, the form will load and show itself. Note that only one WebBrowser is visible at a time, the rest are tabbed. After about 5 seconds (while the winforms event loop is basically idling) the program will crash due to an exception in mshtml.dll. Below is the call stack that i pulled:

[image: Call Stack]

and the disassembler:

[image]

The mouse cursor is where the program breaks. I've doubled checked all of the html and it is all valid. I can load up the first half and the second half of the html separately without crashing. Only when all is loaded it will fail. I've also tried cutting down the number of browsers in half, and doubling the amount of html they individually show, which ended up with the same result. Also tried dynamically loading the html in each web browser when they are first opened.

It seems to me there is some kind of shared memory between all web browser instances, and it eventually just gets corrupted or something.

I'm pretty much at a loss here. I was thinking of possibly replacing the WebBrowser with CefSharp browser, but I don't want to go that route just yet if its not necessary.

Comment: Oh dear, you seem to have no real idea how big and fat a browser is.  You'll want to spend more time looking at the Task Manager's Processes tab to get an idea how much memory is required to get a particular job done.  You'll get a good hang of it after a while, being able to predict this kind of problem up front and avoid shooting the left foot.

Comment: It was only taking up about 700mb. It has plenty of room to expand if it needed to.